# Ascending order sorting in list of dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, dictionary

How can I sort a list in ascending order without key matching?

Every key is unique and need sorting keys.

Input:

```
[{23: (1, 5)}, 
{59: (2, 3)}, 
{45: (2, 9)}, 
{28: (3, 6)}]
```

The output should be like this (Sorting based on keys of dict):

```
[{23: (1, 5)}, 
{28: (3, 6)},
{45: (2, 9)},
{59: (2, 3)}]
```

Comment: You know that dictionaries often have multiple keys, right?

Comment: I don't understand your question. what are you trying to say @ScottHunter

Comment: What if you had a dictionary with 2 keys?  For example: `{1:(1,1), 99:(1,1)}`.  Where should this appear in your sorted list?

Comment: Why don't you put your data like `{23: (1, 5), 59: (2, 3)}` etc. sorting can be done after and an OrderedDict can be used if you need a dict like structure

Comment: It won't have two keys. complete list follow the above mentioned pattern

Comment: @MuhammadHaseebKhan In which case why are you using a dict? This entire problem doesn't make sense.

Comment: @miradulo I wasn't thinking in another way. The chris_rands approach seems easy. But I am just thinking how someone will solve this type of problem.

Comment: They'll hopefully solve this problem by changing their data structure.

Comment: @miradulo Yeah, I agree with you but we should have a solution of every type of problem. I think Martin's provided solution can be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your dictionaries always only have a single key then in Python 2.x:

```
print sorted([{23: (1, 5)}, {59: (2, 3)}, {45: (2, 9)}, {28: (3, 6)}])
```

Would give:

```
[{23: (1, 5)}, {28: (3, 6)}, {45: (2, 9)}, {59: (2, 3)}]
```

By default in Python 2.x using `sorted()` will result in a correctly sorted list.

For Python 3.x:

```
print(sorted([{23: (1, 5)}, {59: (2, 3)}, {45: (2, 9)}, {28: (3, 6)}], key=lambda x: next(iter(x))))
```

This uses a lambda function to extract the first (and only) key from the dictionary and use that as the sorting key.

Comment: This only works in Python 2, since dict_keys cannot be indexed in Python 3.

Comment: I am using python 3 and can you plz elaborate your answer?

Comment: In Python 2, you don't need the key argument at all I think (unless I remember incorrectly how it sorts a list of dicts)

Comment: There's no need to create a list, you can use something like: `lambda x: next(iter(x))`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, have updated accordingly.